# Mongoose get data from joining two model

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two model CRM Model and CRM STATUS model . _id and crm_id is same in two model . any id can have many status document .  i want to find last updated status of each id from CRM STATUS model in nodejs .

CRM MODEL

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a16a6481dac972b9cf22978"),   /// join this 
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-23T10:43:20.450Z"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-23T10:43:20.450Z"),
        "name" : "istiaque ahmad",
        "shop_name" : "soul dance",
        "address" : "dfsdfsd",
        "phone" : "01764199657",
        "email" : "nahid@gmail.com",
        "website" : "facebook.com",
        "comment" : "defdfsdfsdf",
        "interest" : "ddsfsdfsdf",
        "reference" : "dfsdfsdf",
        "__v" : 0
```

CRM STATUS

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1a89041fe4313394da0db6"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-11-26T09:27:32.725Z"), ///last updated
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-26T09:27:32.725Z"),
    "crm_id" : "5a1a48c5796ee01e90b618b6",  // join this 
    "name" : "nahid hasan",
    "shop_name" : "gift gallary",
    "status" : "dsadsdsada", /// find this 
    "__v" : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "Join" some models if you are using "references" in your Shemas.

have a look at [Mongoose Populate Documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this query

```
db.crm.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "crmstatus",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "crm_id",
      as: "status"
    }
  },
  {$unwind: {path: "$status", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
  {$sort: {"status.updatedAt": -1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      name: {$first: "$name"},
      //... add fields as you need 
      status: {$first: "$status"}
    }
  }
])
```